# Ping Windows Hosts unreachable

Tags: ping

Please, I have done some tests with **Ping** command.

My question is: why Ping in green arrow works and in red arrow didn't work ?

[image: MyFigure]

Answer (score 2):

You have configured your Windows firewalls to block the Ping, which is the default. Ubuntu does not by default block pings.

By opening the Windows Firewall control panel and allowing ICMP types `echo-request` in and `echo-reply` out, the Windows machines will be pingable.